# Inodes limit on VPS and Cloud Server

Tags: linux, cloud-hosting

I'm currently stack with a VPS server, so I'm planning to move on a Cloud server.

but I don't have enough knowledge on Linux (Centos or Ubunto server), so I asked the Cloud server provider and here is reply from them:

> There's no such thing as unlimited inodes, as an operating system will
>   always have a limit of how many files it can hold. The better question
>   and answer is, no we do not set a hard limit on the cloud server like
>   we do on the VPS server. The limit is a very fair limit given the
>   structure of the VPS and is very common with Hardware VPS', as since
>   there is an inode limit that every OS has and there's an operating
>   system that is running on the Hardware Node that contains the
>   virutalized operating systems, there's gotta be stricter limits. The
>   Cloud Server removes that limit due to the was it's virtualized, but
>   you still are grounded by whatever the limit is of your operating
>   system.

But I don't understand the limitation on linux except hard disk space, Any one please help me what is limitation with linux inodes or whatever it says.

NOTE: As I will host 100+ CMS site I will have 15,00,000+ small files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I reply to your [yesterday's question](https://serverfault.com/questions/743658/preventing-vps-server-crash-for-inodes-and-memory-limit/743709#743709) - inodes are limited by design, as it is something like telephone list of your filesystem. See more detailed information [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Number of inodes available is defined when creating filesystem and is (more or less) based on filesystem size, so you need to have big filesystem to have many small files, even total size of that files are lower than filesystem.

You should think about using multiple server and distribute whose sites across multiple servers (like hosting about 20 sites per server).

Comment: What about the cloude server they said, they don't set any hard limit? Cloud server plan will have 1vCore + 1GB RAM + 40GB SSD. Also what is the best OS should I choose? Ubuntu or Centos 7?

Comment: Yep, there is no hard limit. It is just a feature of filesystem by-design, nothing something what is limmited by provider. OS is nothing important in this, maybe you will get better performance if you will (and can) host your files on ReiserFS, AFAIK this FS is designed to host bzilions of files. BTW are you planning to host 100+ PHP based sites on machine with 1GB of RAM only? It will not work at all (only if you have really, really tiny number of visitors of those sites.).

Answer (score 0):

If your really worried about inodes one thing i may suggest is to get a dedicated private server running a hypervisor. 
That way you could set up multiple virtual machines and isolate groups of sites

one thing to note is i have my own vps with my company and on a  100G cent7 vps i have over 100000000 inodes not including tmpfs

You could likely host what your talking about on one similarly but i would not recommend running email on the same server as these sites with such a high inode count in use.

Comment: There is no need to put a signature block on your posts as the system inserts one for you with a link to your profile.

Comment: thanks, but I was asking about centos 7 OS limitation as they said "no we do not set a hard limit on the cloud server like we do on the VPS server."

Comment: You can use partitions and mounts to help limit the impact of multiple high inode sites. The VPS i have is running cent 7.1 64bit